# Apache doesn't start after reinstallation

Tags: apache2, debian

before you ask, yes I already searched for this problem and looked at the few other answeres but none of them helped. I reinstalled apache2 and now it always give me this message (after using "journalctl | tail"):

```
    Mai 21 19:12:13 v14268 sshd[23964]: Received                         
    disconnect from 212.73.136.72 port 43340:11: Bye Bye         
    [preauth]
    Mai 21 19:12:13 v14268 sshd[23964]: Disconnected from 
    invalid user ait 212.73.136.72 port 43340 [preauth]
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache 
    HTTP Server...
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 apachectl[23971]: AH00526: 
    Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf- 
    enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 apachectl[23971]: Invalid 
    command 'Alias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a 
    module not included in the server configuration
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 apachectl[23971]: Action 
    'start' failed.
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 apachectl[23971]: The Apache 
    error log may have more information.
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 systemd[1]: apache2.service: 
    Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 systemd[1]: apache2.service: 
    Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 systemd[1]: Failed to start The 
    Apache HTTP Server.
```

There is no error log file and even the apache2 support page doesn't show me a solution for this. I'm using Debian 10.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does say in that output `Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` So have you looked at line 3 of that file?

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

```
Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 apachectl[23971]: AH00526: 
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf- 
enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:
Mai 21 19:12:32 v14268 apachectl[23971]: Invalid 
command 'Alias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a 
module not included in the server configuration
```

That means that in line 3 of the file `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` you are using an `Alias` command that Apache doesn't understand.

Most likely that's because the Apache module `mod_alias` is not activated. Run

```
sudo a2enmod alias
```

to activate it.